# Can I loop through an array while calling a function

Tags: javascript

```
const students = ['John', 'Mark'];
const weight = [92, 85]
const height = [1.88, 1.76]

function yourBodyMass(name, funct, mass, height) {
  console.log(`${name} your BMI is ${funct(mass, height)}.`)
}

function bodyMass(mass, height) {
 const BMI = mass / height ** 2;
  return BMI;
}

function loopData() {
 for (let i of students) {
  return yourBodymass(students[i], bodyMass)
 }
}
```

Now I want to loop through students so that I don't have to declare the yourBodyMass function again and again.
Plz tell IF this is even possible.

Comment: I assume you want to call the function `yourBodymass(students[i], bodyMass, weight[i], height[i])` - *without* a `return` before it

Comment: if you call [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) within the loop's body, it will end the function in the first iteration ...

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a bit of messy here. I think what you want is something like this:

```
const students = ['John', 'Mark'];
const weight = [92, 85]
const height = [1.88, 1.76]

function yourBodyMass(student_name, func, mass, height) {
    console.log(student_name + ' your BMI is ' + func(mass, height));

}

function bodyMass(mass, height) {
    const BMI = mass / height ** 2;
    return BMI;
}

function loopData() {
    for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i += 1) {
        yourBodyMass(students[i], bodyMass, weight[i], height[i]);
    }
}
```

If I were you I would start simplifying your code by deleting yourBodyMass function, like:

```
const students = ['John', 'Mark'];
const weight = [92, 85]
const height = [1.88, 1.76]

function getBMI(weight, height) {
    return weight / height ** 2;
}

function loopData() {
    for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i += 1) {
        let BMI = getBMI(weight[i], height[i]);
        console.log(students[i] + ' your BMI is ' + BMI);
    }
}
```

Noted that I've changed the name of your function bodyMass to getBMI, which I think is more descriptive and could help you to have a cleaner code.

Answer (score 1):

To add to [the answer of @vanowm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72688139/17438890), I would also that if you have a collection of students with three attributes, name, weight and height, you should keep these attributes together in a student object / instance and put these in an array. The simplest way to do this is:

```
const students = [
   { name: 'John', weight: 92, height: 1.88},
   { name: 'Mark', weight: 85, height: 1.76},
];
```

Now you can use a forEach loop:

```
students.forEach(student => {
   yourBodyMass(student.name, bodyMass, student.weight, student.height)
});
```

```js
const students = [{
  name: 'John',
  weight: 92,
  height: 1.88
}, {
  name: 'Mark',
  weight: 85,
  height: 1.76
}];

function yourBodyMass(name, funct, mass, height) {
  console.log(`${name} your BMI is ${funct(mass, height)}.`)
}

function bodyMass(mass, height) {
  const BMI = mass / height ** 2;
  return BMI;
}

students.forEach((student) => {
      yourBodyMass(student.name, bodyMass, student.weight, student.height)
    })
```

Comment: `answer of @vanowm above` there is no guaranteed order of the answers, so `above`, `below`, ... is pointless, and also a username can change. If you want to reference an answer you can use the `share` button below the answer you want to reference, and use that link to reference that answer.

Comment: @t.niese Thanks, I was looking for how to do that :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are four issues with your code:

1. the return statement will terminate loop and exit function after first item in the array
2. there is no `yourBodymass()` function, it's `youBodyMass()` (see missing capital letter?)
3. when you use `of` in the `for` loop, the `i` will have the value of the array, not index
4. you are not sending any `weight` and `height` data to the `yourBodyMass` function

Try fix these issues yourself without looking at the solution.

```js
const students = ['John', 'Mark'];
const weight = [92, 85]
const height = [1.88, 1.76]

function yourBodyMass(name, funct, mass, height) {
  console.log(`${name} your BMI is ${funct(mass, height)}.`)
}

function bodyMass(mass, height) {
 const BMI = mass / height ** 2;
  return BMI;
}

function loopData() {
 for (let i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
  yourBodyMass(students[i], bodyMass, weight[i], height[i])
 }
}

loopData()
```